# psycopg2 - TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: database, postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I'm performing the postgres query with psycopg2, stored in function columnsearch(). My aim is to be able to view the data in each field by using the column name in the return statement. I'm receiving the error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Does anyone know how I can rectify this?

```
def columnsearch():
     con = psycopg2.connect(connectstring)
     cur = con.cursor(cursor_factory=e.DictCursor)
     cur.execute("SELECT * FROM radio_archive_ind.radio_archive_ind WHERE tape_number = 'TP00001'")
     rows = cur.fetchone()
     for r in rows:
             return r["tape_number"]

print columnsearch()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `.fetchone()` returns [a single sequence](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchone) so you can just do:

```
def columnsearch():
     con = psycopg2.connect(connectstring)
     cur = con.cursor(cursor_factory=e.DictCursor)
     cur.execute("""SELECT * 
                      FROM radio_archive_ind.radio_archive_ind 
                     WHERE tape_number = 'TP00001'""")
     row = cur.fetchone()
     return row["tape_number"]
```